# Plotly.js 3D Scatter plot showgrid : false not working

Tags: plotly

http://codepen.io/rudi8292/pen/QEmKPG

The above code doesnt allow me to hide grid lines in 3DScatter plot.

I am trying to hide x,y,z grid lines using the following option :

```
  var layout = {
    title: 'Plotly Graph',
    xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    yaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    zaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    margin: {
        l: 0,
        r: 0,
        b: 0,
        t: 0
    },

    showlegend: true,
    legend: {
        "x": "0",
        "margin.r": "120"
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot('plotly-div', data, layout, {

    displaylogo: false
});
```

This is what i am aiming to do :

http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/KpLVzv

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the scene fields to manipulate the xaxis , yaxis and zaxis custom values.

```
  var layout = {
    scene : {
        xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    yaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    zaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        autotick: true,
        ticks: '',
        showticklabels: false
    },
    margin: {
        l: 0,
        r: 0,
        b: 0,
        t: 0
    },
    showlegend: true,
    legend: {
        "x": "0",
        "margin.r": "120"
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot('plotly-div', data, layout, {

    displaylogo: false
});
```

http://codepen.io/rudi8292/pen/XKENgx

Thanks a lot Étienne Tétreault-Pinard